# High score for both?

Tags: 2048

In the new update for 2048 on iOS devices, you can play with up to four players via Game Center. If I am playing with one other person, will the score I receive become a new highscore for me and the other person(if I beat my high score while playing multiplayer)? Or will that high score pertain only to me?